# ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I followed the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop#viewmodel) to create `viewModel` instance and it works perfectly. However, when there is any `viewModel` in the `@composable`, Android Studio isn't able to render the preview and with the error code `ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview`. Anyone got any solution?

P.S. using compose version `1.0.0-alpha06`

Comment: currently the preview works if pass viewModel through func parameter, but it s weird that if I have many viewmodels

Comment: `@Preview` is meant mostly for the ends of the composable hierarchy (e.g., rows in a list), and those composables should neither receive nor instantiate viewmodels. Rather, they should receive normal parameters, `State` objects, and lambdas for callbacks -- things that you can easily provide default values for in the composable declaration.

Comment: I can see some using `mock` when testing. Wonder if  there is any similar thing when using preview. It will be inconvenient of not able to preview a parent screen if any of children composable using any viewmodel

Comment: @CommonsWare Not according to this doc. Composables can take a viewmodel. I think the Android team just needs to add the support for it:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: I faced up the same problem. My workaround is to made my viewModel nullable and provide default value for the preview.

Comment: There is a `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel` but, I preview didn't work either with this.

Comment: Posting your source code might help in finding the problem.

Comment: https://jetc.dev/slack/2021-04-17-preview-viewmodel.html

Comment: Check by removing other components. I had that error and it wasn't because of my viewmodel but because of another material component, which sadly I now forget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get preview in composable functions that depend on a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089816/how-to-get-preview-in-composable-functions-that-depend-on-a-view-model)

Comment: Hi I have figure out a way to run preview composable on emulator even if they are hilt ViewModel injected check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70385823/6938847)

Answer (score 19):

You could use an approach that looks like this which will show up in the recommended video bellow:

```
@Composable
fun TestView(
    action: MainActions,
    viewModel: OnboardViewModel = getViewModel()
) {
    TestUI(onClick = viewModel.clickMethod())
}

@Composable
fun TestUI(onClick: () -> Unit) {}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestUIPreview() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        TestUI(onClick = {})
    }
}
```

There is a recommendation from google in this video at the selected time: https://youtu.be/0z_dwBGQQWQ?t=573

Comment: I'm using hilt and when I use `= hiltViewModel()` it still shows: `ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview`

Comment: The example tries to show the situation where your  UI and the ViewModel are decoupled. The only way the viewmodel talks to the UI is trough method references. 

So if you are getting this error is because your ViewModel is in the @Preview which it shouldn't.

Comment: @Dr.jacky u find solution for yours case?

Comment: @Morozov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089816/how-to-get-preview-in-composable-functions-that-depend-on-a-view-model/69089891?noredirect=1#comment122708029_69089891

Comment: He is doing it in a way that is not supposed to be done. You cannot initialize a viewmodel inside of a preview

Comment: @Morozov Follow what C. Hellmann did; As google does the same: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state;;; Create an extra composable (`HelloContent`) and use THAT in the preview

Comment: Th explanation given as the correct answer in the provided link is insane. Creating a fake repository.
Just provide the methods you need as parameters for the UI Composable and if you need any data just provide some mocks.

Comment: This doesn't work if your composable uses any other composables that uses a viewmodel. Say, if your Scaffold contains any buttons that instantiate a viewmodel, you cannot preview your scaffold

Comment: This does work, but you need to adapt your approach as no solution fits all problems. Also, most people that disagreed to this solution were following an anti pattern approach. I recommend you review your implementation with code from trusted sources.

Comment: Yes, it works in small, bottom tree composables, but it is infeasible for even med-sized apps. Using the `viewModel()` or `hiltViewmodel()` shouldn't be anti-pattern when it is literally a standard component in androidx. As it is right now, The only way to use @Preview is for your top-level composable to have an insane and unmanagable amount of parameters! That's just *not* feasible or even fun to work with. They should really rework either viewmodels-within-composables or the @Preview-feature. We need to be able to access our root level viewmodel anywhere in the tree AND use @Preview.

Answer (score 13):

I had exactly the same problem.
The solution was: Extend the ViewModel with an interface

ComposeView:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(myVm: IMyViewModel = MyViewModel()) {
    Text(text = myVm.getTextA())
}


@Preview()
@Composable
fun MyScreenPreview() {
    MyScreen(myVm = MyViewModelPreview())
}
```

ViewModel:

```
abstract class IMyViewModel : ViewModel(){
    abstract val dynamicValue: StateFlow<String>
    abstract fun getTextA() : String
}

class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel() {
    private val _dynamicValue: MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("")
    override val dynamicValue: StateFlow<String> = _dynamicValue

    init {
    }

    override fun getTextA(): String {
        return "Details: ${EntityDb.getAllEntities().lastOrNull()?.details}"
    }
}

class MyViewModelPreview(override val dynamicValue: StateFlow<String> =    MutableStateFlow("no data")) : IMyViewModel() {
    override fun getTextA(): String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since [LiveEdit](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/iterative-development#limitations) is now available, you don't need to use Compose Preview for a whole screen with `ViewModel` anymore. Just debug the app with **Live Edit**. This is also how it's done in Flutter with "hot reload". In Flutter there isn't even something like Compose Preview.

I would recommend using Compose Preview only for smaller composables that don't have a `ViewModel`.

So you don't have to write all this boilerplate code with extending the `ViewModel` or passing primitives from the `ViewModel` into a sub composable.

Keep in mind that one requirement to use LiveEdit, is to use [AndroidStudio Flamingo](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) or later.

Comment: One can have multiple `@Preview` to see different configurations at the same time (like dark and light mode for instance).  How can this be done with LiveEdit?

Answer (score 2):

The @Preview annotated composable class should be agnostic from viewmodel.
i use this solution adding an extra class with models as input

```
@Composable
fun TabScreen(
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val details = viewModel.details.observeAsState()

    Tabs(
        details.value
    )
}

@Composable
fun Tabs(
    details: Details?
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
}


@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun TabsPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(DetailsPreview::class)
    details: Details?
) {
    AppTheme {
        Tabs(details)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is DetailsPreview::class

Answer (score 0):

You could use interfaces and [hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack).

```
interface IMyViewModel {

    fun getTextA() : String

}

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel(), IMyViewModel {
    fun getTextA() : String {
        //do some cool stuff
    }
}

class MyViewModelPreview() : IMyViewModel {
    fun getTextA() : String {
        //do some mock stuff
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(myVm = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>()) {
    Text(text = myVm.getTextA())
}


@Preview()
@Composable
fun MyScreenPreview() {
    MyScreen(myVm = MyViewModelPreview())
}
```

In this point MyViewModel is an implementation of IMyViewModel annotated with @HiltViewModel and hiltViewModel make all the required wired for you, In preview you could use any other simple mock implementation.

If you need to provide some dependency to your view model use injected constructor with dagger injection(already supported by hilt). Obviously this dependency should be paced on your actual viewmodel and your preview implementations need to be just a wrapper class with no other dependency since they function is just satisfy arguments

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myDependencyRepositoryOne: MyDependencyRepositoryOne,
    private val myDependencyRepositoryTwo: MyDependencyRepositoryTwo)
: ViewModel(), IMyViewModel {
    fun getTextA() : String {
        //do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

[Here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose/) is another useful resource related to viewmodel injection in compose

Comment: What if i have tons of dependencies in the `viewModel`?

Comment: You could use injected constructor since hilt is built over dagger. I edited my answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

It's because some features aren't supported with compose preview. like if you're using Hilt. Maybe it works with Koin i'm not sure.
If anyone's got the problem you can refer to official android developer document [Compose Preview and ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#preview-viewmodel) to see some solution.

Answer (score -3):

what I am using:

```
  @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
         MyMVIApp1Theme {
           val myViewModel = remember { AppViewModel() }
           Greeting(viewModel = myViewModel,"Android")
         }
    }
```

Comment: constructor of your viewModel doesn't have any parameters?) like injected repositories/interactors?