# How to get preview in composable functions that depend on a view model?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

### Problem description

I would like to have the preview of my `HomeScreen` composable function in my `HomeScreenPrevieiw` preview function. However this is not being possible to do because I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$FakeViewModelStoreOwner$1.getViewModelStore(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:709)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.<init>(ViewModelProvider.kt:105)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:82)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:72)
    at com.example.crud.ui.screens.home.HomeScreenKt.HomeScreen(HomeScreen.kt:53)
    at com.example.crud.ui.screens.home.HomeScreenKt.HomeScreenPreview(HomeScreen.kt:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    ...
```

### My code

This is my `HomeScreen` code:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateToDetailsAction: () -> Unit,
    openCardDetailsAction: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val cities = viewModel.cities.observeAsState(listOf())
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { HomeAppBar() },
        floatingActionButton = { HomeFab(navigateToDetailsAction) }
    ) {
        HomeContent(cities) { id -> openCardDetailsAction(id) }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my preview function:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    HomeScreen(navigateToDetailsAction = {}, openCardDetailsAction = {})
}
```

My view model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: CityRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val cities: LiveData<List<City>> = repository.allCities.asLiveData()
}
```

Repository:

```
@ViewModelScoped
class CityRepository @Inject constructor(appDatabase: AppDatabase) {
    private val dao by lazy { appDatabase.getCityDao() }

    val allCities by lazy { dao.getAllCities() }

    suspend fun addCity(city: City) = dao.insert(city)

    suspend fun updateCity(city: City) = dao.update(city)

    suspend fun deleteCity(city: City) = dao.delete(city)

    suspend fun getCityById(id: Int) = dao.getCityById(id)

}
```

AppDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = [City::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getCityDao() : CityDao
}
```

### My failed attempt

I thought it might be a problem with the view model being passed as the default parameter of my `HomeScreen` and so I decided to do it this way:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navigateToDetailsAction: () -> Unit,
    openCardDetailsAction: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val cities = viewModel.cities.observeAsState(listOf())
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { HomeAppBar() },
        floatingActionButton = { HomeFab(navigateToDetailsAction) }
    ) {
        HomeContent(cities) { id -> openCardDetailsAction(id) }
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work (I keep getting the same error), and it's not good for testing as it would prevent me from testing my `HomeScreen` with a mocked view model.

Comment: You could pass `cities` into `HomeScreen()` (in your second code snippet) and eliminate the dependency on the viewmodel.

Comment: This is a really good idea, however it could be a problem if my `HomeScreen` had any more dependencies tied to `HomeViewModel`. Or, ideally, a screen does not need to worry about the view model that is "related" to it?

Comment: Google's Jim Sproch has stated on a couple of occasions that you should minimize the number of composables into which you pass a `ViewModel`. More generally, `@Preview` is designed for "leaf" composables, not full screens. To translate into classic Android patterns, you can preview custom views more readily than you can preview fragments or activities. There are workarounds for this, such as having the viewmodel implement an interface, have the composable depend on the interface, and use a one-off implementation of the interface for the `@Preview`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exactly one of the reasons why the view model is passed with a default value. In the preview, you can pass a test object:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    val viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    // setup viewModel as you need it to be in the preview
    HomeScreen(viewModel = viewModel, navigateToDetailsAction = {}, openCardDetailsAction = {})
}
```

Since you have a repository, you can do the same thing you would do to test the view model.

1. Create interface for `CityRepository`

```
interface CityRepositoryI {
    val allCities: List<City>

    suspend fun addCity(city: City)
    suspend fun updateCity(city: City)
    suspend fun deleteCity(city: City)
    suspend fun getCityById(id: Int)
}
```

2. Implement it for `CityRepository`:

```
@ViewModelScoped
class CityRepository @Inject constructor(appDatabase: AppDatabase) : CityRepositoryI {
    private val dao by lazy { appDatabase.getCityDao() }

    override val allCities by lazy { dao.getAllCities() }

    override suspend fun addCity(city: City) = dao.insert(city)

    override suspend fun updateCity(city: City) = dao.update(city)

    override suspend fun deleteCity(city: City) = dao.delete(city)

    override suspend fun getCityById(id: Int) = dao.getCityById(id)
}
```

3. Create `FakeCityRepository` for testing purposes:

```
class FakeCityRepository : CityRepositoryI {
    // predefined cities for testing
    val cities = listOf(
        City(1)
    ).toMutableStateList()

    override val allCities by lazy { cities }

    override suspend fun addCity(city: City) {
        cities.add(city)
    }

    override suspend fun updateCity(city: City){
        val index = cities.indexOfFirst { it.id == city.id }
        cities[index] = city
    }

    override suspend fun deleteCity(city: City) {
        cities.removeAll { it.id == city.id }
    }

    override suspend fun getCityById(id: Int) = cities.first { it.id == id }
}
```

So you can pass it into your view model: `HomeViewModel(FakeCityRepository())`

You can do the same with `AppDatabase` instead of a repository, it all depends on your needs. Check out more about [Hilt testing](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing)

p.s. I'm not sure if this will build, since I don't have some of your classes, but you should have caught the idea.

Comment: I use hilt and when I do like `val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ProductsListViewModel>()` in the preview method, it still says `ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview`

Comment: @Dr.jacky As I said in my answer, from Preview you should pass `FakeCityRepository()` instead of calling `hiltViewModel`

Answer (score 4):

Hi like @Philip Dukhov has explained in his answer is correct and ideally should be done this way.

But I would like to suggest a workaround cause it requires a lot of setups like fakes and manually creating intermediate objects.

You can get your preview working on the emulator by using a custom run configuration and using a specific Activity as PreviewActivity with @AndroidEntryPoint Annotation.

You can follow a detailed guide with screen shot and internals from the blog **I have published** from [here](https://chetangupta.net/preview-hilt/)

Or simply you can

[image]

[image]

[image]

Activity Needs to have

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltPreviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
....
}
```

you need to manually copy-paste preview composable into `setContent{..}` of the HiltPreviewActivity.

Run from the toolbar, not from preview shortcut, check guide for mode details.

[image]

Comment: `Warning: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter` How to fix this? doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna Try to check `Skip Activity validation` in `Launch Options`, then it will run perfectly.