# ViewModels creation is not supported in Preview Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have next screen:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun AccountListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AccountListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
```

And I want to make a preview for this screen.

I'm trying to do this the following way:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun AccountListScreenPreview() {
    AccountListScreen(
        navController = rememberNavController(),
        viewModel = hiltViewModel()
    )
}
```

But unfortunately I get the following error when trying to build a preview:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModels creation is not supported
> in Preview

How can this problem be solved? Also here is [code](https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/4576c7e7850b45011f182030a4a5b0ae) of some my classes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get preview in composable functions that depend on a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089816/how-to-get-preview-in-composable-functions-that-depend-on-a-view-model) I see your comment under my reply, but I don't understand how this question is different.

Comment: No, I still don't understand how to apply this answer to my case so that I can display my screen.  I don't have a callback implemented and I don't think I need it. if you need to provide a little more code, you tell me, because I don't understand how to solve the problem yet.sry

Answer (score 2):

What I do in my apps is create a wrapper for my root composable that gets the state from the viewmodel and passes that to a 2nd Composable, where I have my actual content. If there are callbacks that the composable needs to call into the viewModel, then I define those as an interface that the viewModel implements. That way my composable, which I want to preview, receives just a State class and, if needed, an interface for the callbacks, which I can easily stub out.

Something like this:

```
@Composable
fun CityScreen(
    viewModel: CityViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState()
    CityScreen(
        state = state.value,
        callbacks = viewModel,
        modifier = modifier,
    )
}

@Composable
private fun CityScreen(
    state: CityState,
    callbacks: CityCallbacks,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: I kind of understood the idea, but unfortunately I can't apply it to my specific case. As I understand it, you are already doing a preview in the second section of the code
`CityScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wanna test with your preview, you can mock view model injections(like showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089816/how-to-get-preview-in-composable-functions-that-depend-on-a-view-model)) or the view model itself.

To mock the view model you can create an interface of your view model, in this case it should be `abstract class` to subclass from `ViewModel`:

```
abstract class AccountListViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // interface visible to your view
}

@HiltViewModel
class AccountListViewModelImpl: AccountListViewModel() {
   // implementation which works using dependencies
}
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
@Composable
fun AccountListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AccountListViewModel = hiltViewModel<AccountListViewModelImpl>()
) {

}

@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun AccountListScreenPreview() {
    AccountListScreen(
        navController = rememberNavController(),
        viewModel = object: AccountListViewModel() {
            // implementation with test data
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't say much about interactive preview, If you are interested in running a preview of your `hiltViewModels` on an emulator, you can create a custom run configuration for an activity that is marked with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

PreviewActivity used by current UI toolkit package doesn't have Hilt support.
I have an article explaining its steps with screenshots, check from [here](https://chetangupta.net/preview-hilt/)